# Android fullscreen issue on android 4.1

Tags: android, android-activity, fullscreen, android-navigation, android-fullscreen

I'm working on Android 4.1 and application must run on Piranha Ultra III Tab 10.1.

I'll use http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/ui-overview.html for naming reference for my question; Status bar and navigation bar...

I tried too many things

Mostly founded on Google and Stackoverflow is;

**1)**

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

This code just disabled status bar but not navigation bar.

**2)**

I tried Google's fullscreen example. That project hid both navigation bar and status bar but everytime when I tap or any gesture movement, navigation bar is shown. I wrote events for gestures and every gesture movement, I tried to hid again but didn't work too..

**3)**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility%28int%29

I tried this too but same as Google's fullscreen example...

```
int newVis = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;

newVis |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

newVis |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;

newVis |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE;

newVis |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;

newVis |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

// newVis |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;

v.setSystemUiVisibility(newVis);
```

---

Also I tried Samples with XML (style / layout / manifest) but no result...

Is there any other way to doin' this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hide the navigation buttons, Android force them to reappear on every interaction, because you don't want your users to be locked out in your app.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION).

As far as I know, Android doesn't allow you to hide "permanently" (with or without gestures to pop it up again, except for Immersive Mode) the navigation bar, or maybe with root...

Comment: Yes, I get it but how games disablin' navigation bar when playin' the game ?

Comment: I don't know any game that do that on Android versions before Kit Kat. Hide the status bar, yes. Hide the navigation bar, no.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your manifest under the activity you want

```
<activity
    android:name="your activity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks @youssefhassan, but as I wrote, I already tried XML things. This is not workin' :/